# Hammer Drill on Stone Slab

Tags: drill, stone

I have a concrete wall with stone slabs on top, I want to drill into the stone slabs to attach a fence, they are around 2 inches thick, can I use a hammer drill or will this crack the stone?

Comment: A hammercdrill might loosen the stone cappings…

Comment: Do not use a hammer drill on the tile surface, you are risking to break it down. Use a small drill bit to make a pilot hole, then enlarge the hole with a larger bit. Just need patient when dealing with fragile materials.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the fence posts need a hole bigger than about half an inch (probably more like 2 to 8 inches) and you want a clean round hole, use a diamond core bit not a hammer.

A "hammer drill" (the kind that vibrates when you lean on it) will help you make small holes in stone, suitable for screws but not for a fence post.  A more powerful rotary hammer on a thin slab might break it in half.

Comment: Oh, excellent point!

Comment: A possibility is a granite counter top installer . They can cut hoes in granite of any size but it would cost money and I do not know how willing they are to make a house call.

Comment: I've seen the counter people do it.  An ordinary drill and a $50 core bit gets through a countertop.   There is some skill involved in starting it in the right place without dancing the bit and scratching up the counter.  I wouldn't attempt it on a $1000 countertop myself.  But if it's stone tiles that cost $20 I'd buy the bit, maybe buy a couple of slabs to practice on, and go at it.